# OSStatus error -50?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just received a result code(-50) returned from ExtAudioFileWrite().

And I didnt't find the information about this result code in "Extended Audio File Services Reference".

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Error -50 means there’s an error in the arguments you’ve passed to a function. Make sure that all the arguments you’re passing to `ExtAudioFileWrite()` are correct.

Answer (score 13):

This error code is declared in MacErrors.h of the CarbonCore framework. -50 is `paramErr`. IOW, one of your parameters is invalid. So you will need to verify your parameters, buffer sizes, arguments that you pass and so on to locate the parameter which has been flagged.

Comment: `paramErr` has often been used as a "catch-all" sort of error, so it might be hard to narrow down. An invalid parameter can mean almost anything.

Comment: Pay closer attention to AudioStreamBasicDescription

Comment: Good answer.. [MacErrors.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacErrors.h)

Answer (score 0):

errSecParam                              = -50,     /* One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid. */

you can find all error in Security->SecBase.h

Answer (score -1):

Add the code to the initialization of project

```
NSArray *availableInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *port = [availableInputs objectAtIndex:0];  //built in mic for your case
    NSError *portErr = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:port error:&portErr];
```